# JPA query Select new

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Query:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.abc.cba.domain.Attachment(ia.createdBy, 
ia.fileName, ia.contentType, ia.someClass, ia.otherClass) from Attachment ia 
where ia.someClass=?1")
List<Attachment> findAllBySomeClass(SomeClass someClass);
```

And constructor:

```
public Attachment(User createdBy, String fileName, String contentType, SomeClass someClass, OtherClass otherClass) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.contentType = contentType;
    this.someClass = someClass;
    this.otherClass = otherClass;
}
```

I don't get any Attachments. But when I execute this:

```
@Query("SELECT ia from Attachment ia where ia.someClass=?1")
List<Attachment> findAllBySomeClass(SomeClass someClass);
```

then i get everything i want. But i don't need all these fields, but only these listed in first query. Why it doesn't work?

From debugging: it doesn't even step into this constructor.

Comment: From debugging you get some SQL sent to the database ...

Comment: Using Spring Data JPA you can use a more convenient technic to work with DTO: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Attachment(User createdBy, String fileName, String contentType, SomeClass someClass, OtherClass otherClass) 
//User, SomeClass, OtherClass wont work here like that
```

As you want to pick relational properties into new tuple object, you have to make proper joins yourself and provide joined objects with query like this

```
SELECT new com.abc.cba.domain.Attachment(user, ia.fileName, ia.contentType (....)) FROM Attachent ia JOIN ia.createdBy user JOIN ......"
```

Comment: It's still the same - i don't get any Attachments. :(

Comment: That is probably because some relations are missing causing INNER JOIN to return empty result set. Double check that createdBy, someClass and otherClass are set in db.

Comment: Yes, that was it. :) It doesn't have to be even joined, the first version without joins works now too. It was all about null otherClass. Thank you very much!

Comment: Im glad I could help

Comment: How can I make this thing work, IF I have null values in 'otherClass' and I don't have the option to fill them?